# How to see java files in project tree in intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working with intellij idea but I can't see the java source files in the project tree. I see the packages, I can open it, but the class files are not displayed. Any idea? This has worked until a few days ago...

Comment: I think this has to due with the fact that I have copied and renamed an existing project.

Answer (score 5):

Under the intelliJ IDEA 14.0.3 community edition, upon launch I don't see my project folders. I found by going into

View > Tool Windows > Project

seems to show the folder structure.. Same as ALT + 1

Answer (score 4):

Below the menubar , on the left there is a dropdown which in your case may be showing "packages" now (because you can see the packages).  From the same dropdown, select "Project Files" below "SCOPES"

Answer (score 2):

You need to check out the project correctly if you are checking out from SVN repo or you must not have selected correct project folder.

You can also configure your project from File->Project Structure check your Source folder is excluded or not.

Also Alt+1 will give you project structure of files in tree format

Answer (score 1):

Check in "Project Structure" (ctrl+alt+shift+S) if you didn't set your source as "Excluded" (in Modules, sources).

Comment: I had this issue. Thanks @Tyco

Answer (score 0):

If you are develop a maven project, you could run `mvn idea:idea` and then open the project in your Intellij, the source files and the project tree would become the shape you like.